# retrieve different morph relationship with its relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, model

the question regarding retrieving polymorphic relationships in Laravel.
the App has have four models :  **Task**, **Team**, **Member** and  **Robot**

---

- The **Task** may be assigned to a **Team** or to **Robot** directly
- The **Team** has **Member**s

i need to retrieve all task with polymorphic relationships (Taskable) and if the taskable is **Team** then retrieve its **Member**s but if it is **Robot** ignore it

([image])

Error
[image]

---

Of course, this error throw because Robot does not has members!
**Could you help me How can I avoid this error or implement the idea in another way?**

Thanks

Of course, this error throw because Robot does not has members!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
  Task::where('taskable','\App\Models\Team')->with('Taskable.Members')->get()
```

You can specifiy where clause to make sure you go not get any of your Robot entries.

---

PS. Please post your actual code as text rather than an image.

Comment: thanks for your time and your edition <3, 
This solution is best for team tasks page.
---------------------------
But for all tasks page, i need to return all tasks (ex : or last 100 ) either assigned to team or to robot.

my issue about how i can add condition if team return members otherwise ignore it

Comment: Toby Allen, your answer is indeed useful,

but i don't have the cast of vote ,, i'm sorry for that